# Facebook reference is unavailable for my project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I try to integrate my app with facebook, I already clone the facebook sdk. Once i create my project, and try to add reference to the facebook sdk through (project properties-->android-->add..), the library is unavailable. Some body please help me, I already follow the instruction in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ (facebook developer site):  I'm stuck when trying to I try Add reference to the Facebook SDK

Answer (score 9):

After trying about 9 or 10 combinations of solutions available on the internet, I finally solved this problem by

```
    1.) Right clicking the supposed library project com_facebook_android
    2.) Clicking Properties/Android
    3.) Checking the small checkbox islibrary
    4.) Click Apply
    5.) Now go back to your android project where you want to reference com_facebook_android 
    6.) Clicking Properties/Android
    7.) Click ADD. 
    PRESTO! behold the magical com_facebook_android library project!!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like old post.. I faced same problem and able to solve it.

Basically, you need to add your library via Project property > java buildpath > project

And, For just in case, add your library via project property > android > library.

After that, just clean your project. you will be able to see your library is properly added.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a notice to the following(copy from the guidebook.):

***Create a new Android project*** for your app or *use your existing project* and add a reference to the Facebook SDK project.

That means the project what you want o add the library is not the **com_facebook_android**.
Maybe this help.
For me I mistaked.

Answer (score 0):

options
1) restart eclipse
2) build/compile or project clean the fb sdk project

you should be able to see the fb reference. i've added
the reference a few times. should work.

Comment: still not working, any other idea? Or can i make a facebook sdk as a reference to my existing project? I already develop one and half way done, so can i reference to fb sdk? If can tell me how.

Comment: I get the answer from this site http://www.radiantsilverlabs.com/content/using-facebook-api-android-windows-starters-guide, very helpful, explain step by step. I just need to create 2 android project, one using the existing source which is point to facebook sdk, and then create new project and make a reference to the previous facebook sdk project I create. Facebook android tutorial site quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. After adding reference to the facebook project it just wasn't adding it. Next time I reopened the settings of the project, the link to facebook project wasn't there anymore.
Restarting Eclipse helped. After restart Eclipse could add the link to the library all right. Must be some Eclipse bug, dunno.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem...i solved by copying ref project into project workplace..